# Image registration and focus stacking

Tags: opencv, throughput

**Background:**
I am looking to align images for a focus stacking application using a smartphone.  Links to images:

First in stack: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEFjJ.jpg), Last in stack: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZJbo.jpg), Final stacked images: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm1bv.png)

I.e. images are nominally the same, BUT contain:

1. Systematic change in FOCUS as the focal plane shifts between images
2. Magnification changes slightly (smartphone feature as focus changes!)
3. Camera moves slightly due to random vibrations.

Images need to be aligned for the focus-stacking APP to work.

**Progress to date:**
I use OpenCV's findTransformECC() to get alignment.  It works well after some experimentation i.e. see [cv2.MOTION_EUCLIDEAN for the warp_mode in ECC image alignment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997891/cv2-motion-euclidean-for-the-warp-mode-in-ecc-image-alignment-method) which was useful to improve the initialization of the Warp matrix:

1. Images aligned at pixel level
2. 60secs to process 8Mpix image (1sec for 0.5Mpix image) (on 3 year old portable PC with OpenCV release libraries)

See stacked image link above.

I briefly investigated a feature detector (SIFT).  It did not align the images well, presumably due to the change in focus between images.

**Code:**

```
 int scale = 1;
 int scaleSmall = 4;
 float scaleDiff = scaleSmall / scale;

     for (i = 0; i< numImages; i++) {
        file = dir + image + to_string(i) + ".jpg";
        col[i] = imread(file);

        resize(col[i], z[i], Size(col[i].cols/scale, col[i].rows/scale));       
        cvtColor(z[i], zg[i], CV_BGR2GRAY);
        resize(zg[i], zgSmall[i],  Size(col[i].cols / scaleSmall, col[i].rows / scaleSmall));
     }

    // Set a 2x3 or 3x3 warp matrix depending on the motion model.
    // See https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/
    // Define the motion model
    const int warp_mode = MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY;

    // Initialize the matrix to identity
    if (warp_mode == MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY) {
        warp_init = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F);
        warp_matrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F);
        warp_matrix_prev = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32F);
        scaleTX = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1, 1, scaleDiff, 1, 1, scaleDiff, 1 / scaleDiff, 1 / scaleDiff, 1);
    }
    else {
        warp_init = Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);
        scaleTX = Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);
        warp_matrix = Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);
        warp_matrix_prev = Mat::eye(2, 3, CV_32F);
        scaleTX = (Mat_<float>(2, 3) << 1, 1, scaleDiff, 1, 1, scaleDiff);
    }

    // Specify the number of iterations.
    int number_of_iterations = 5000;

    // Specify the threshold of the increment
    // in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
    double termination_eps = 1e-8;

    // Define termination criteria
    TermCriteria criteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, number_of_iterations, termination_eps);

    for (i = 1; i < numImages; i++) {
        // Check images right size
        if (zg[0].rows < 10 || zg[1].rows < 10)
            return;

        // Run the ECC algorithm at start to get an initial guess. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
        if (i == 1) {
            findTransformECC(zgSmall[0], zgSmall[i], warp_init, warp_mode, criteria     );

            // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997891/cv2-motion-euclidean-for-the-warp-mode-in-ecc-image-alignment-method
            warp_matrix = warp_init * scaleTX;
        }

        // Warp Matrix from previous iteration is used as initialisation  
        findTransformECC(zg[0], zg[i], warp_matrix, warp_mode,  criteria);

        if (warp_mode != MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY) {
            warpAffine(zg[i], ag[i], warp_matrix, zg[i].size(), INTER_LINEAR + WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
            warpAffine(z[i], acol[i], warp_matrix, zg[i].size(), INTER_LINEAR + WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
        }
        else {
            // Use warpPerspective for Homography
            warpPerspective(z[i], acol[i], warp_matrix, z[i].size(), INTER_LINEAR + WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
            warpPerspective(zg[i], ag[i], warp_matrix, zg[i].size(), INTER_LINEAR + WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
           }
        }
    }
```

**Question:**
Can the image registration speed be significantly improved (using the same hardware)?

Comment: Can you post exemplary images? What settings do you use to align images? Also please post the code.

Comment: See image links and code inserted

Answer (score 1):

there are at least 3 improvements that can be done:

1. 5000 iterations may be unnecessary. Try to limit it to 500. Moreover transforming images to gradient domain may help. See `GetGradient` function from this [tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/).
2. You can assume that perspective effects are negligible so you can change `warp_mode` to `MOTION_AFFINE` to limit the degrees of freedom from 8 to 6.
3. You can also try another, much faster approach that is based on phase correlation (frequency domain). In the standard way it only estimates translation between images but you can transfer them to the log-polar space to get translation, rotation and scale invariance. This [code](https://github.com/Smorodov/LogPolarFFTTemplateMatcher) implements the third approach.

Comment: The Phase Correlation approach is very fast but I'm struggling to get sufficient accuracy.  Any thoughts?   Is it suited to compare an image to an equivalent that is out of focus and slightly out of alignment?